# By using protege can we store & retrieve data's like we doing it on relational database?

Tags: semantic-web, ontology, protege

Hi I very new to semantic web and `Protege`.

Can we store and retrieve data in `Protege` like we do in relational database? Or can we manipulate only models? if yes, do we need RDBMS for storing data and use `Protege` to manage the relationship?.

Can we use protege as replacement for Mysql Database to store and retrieve information?

OR I am completely wrong about what is protege?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple say, `Protege` is a software that helps you to graphically building your ontology. Of cause you can store data (for example `Individual`) in your ontology and query them using a query language. But it really depends on what your data and your query are.